# Pesquisa no Banco Oracle perdendo a sessão

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, session

Bom dia prezados,

eu estou com sérios problemas quanto ao uso do banco de dados Oracle e perder a sessão. O cenário é o seguinte: de milhares que queries realizadas, algumas travam e quando vamos ver se ainda está rodando, elas já nem existem mais no banco. Isto acontece tanto no SQL Developer quanto na própria aplicação Java. Este erro parece acontecer dentro de 1% de várias que rodam. Uma coisa que percebi, é que quanto maior o volume de dados a ser trabalhado na query, mais vezes acontece o erro. O mais interessante é que tanto o SQL Developer quanto a aplicação, ficam esperando resposta do banco, mesmo sem mais existir uma sessão no banco. Se eu pegar esta query e tentar rodar novamente, ela roda normalmente.

Estas queries rodam 7 em paralelo, retornando de segundos a poucos minutos. Se já estiver rodando a mais de 30 minutos, com certeza já perdeu a sessão.

Desculpe se ficou vaga a pergunta, mas não encontrei nenhum padrão para que possa expressar aqui. Gostaria de saber as possíveis causas para ajudar nesta investigação.

Comment: Checou os valores dos parametros de timeout ? Pode ser um deles https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF182

Comment: Eu coloquei para o EJB o timeout de 3600 segundos (1 hora)